# How to list amount of emp in a dept for depts that have more than 5 emp in the dept

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need to know how can I Write a query to display deptno and count of emp in that dept, show only the depts that have more than 5 employees. I tried this:

```
 SELECT  D.DNAME FROM
 dept D WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM emp E 
                WHERE E.DEPTNO  = D.DEPTNO) > 3
```

Though I only got the dept no

Comment: If you tried with that SQL, you did not get dept. no. You didn't get anything, because it's not valid SQL.

Comment: Works for me (Oracle 12.2).

Answer (score 3):

You could use `HAVING` clause to filter rows after aggregation:

```
SELECT d.dname, COUNT(*) AS num_of_emp
FROM dept d
JOIN emp e
  ON d.deptno = e.deptno
GROUP BY d.dname
HAVING COUNT(*) > 5
```

Comment: this doesnt tell the count / amount of emps in the dept that fill the req of 5+ employees

Comment: @micke Sure, I added column with count